SFMC SQL string to get records which are 90 days between TODAY and a date field
I'm having issues with a SFMC SQL string which should get records which have check_in_date 90 days from TODAY. So if today is 28/11/2024, I only want records that have a check in date between 28/11/2024 and 28/02/2025 (90 days). I'm not sure what I'm missing here, but I thought this was the correct query.
WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c < dateadd(day, -90, GETDATE())
The record count was 0 even though I know there should be 80 records here.
I tried this query as well and the record count was still 0.
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, o.Check_In_Date__c, DATEADD(day, -90, GETDATE())) = 2

The current time should be greater than or equal to the past time. Try this:
WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())


Thanks, but that string is still getting records that are greater than 90 days from TODAY. Any other thoughts?

@Sophia All dates are stored as MM/DD/YYYY. Have you considered about it yet?

@Sophia, if you simply need records with a Check_In_Date between 28/11/2024 and 28/02/2025, i.e., a hardcoded time period, then try this:
WHERE o.Check_In_Date >= '2024-11-28'
AND o.Check_In_Date <= '2025-02-28'

Thank you all. I needed a variable date range based on the day the automation runs. I received assistance from another platform, and added in another string to narrow down the records using : WHERE o.Check_In_Date__c >= GETDATE() AND o.Check_In_Date__c < dateadd(day, 90, GETDATE())
